# How does SharePoint Deployment Services actually work?

Tags: sharepoint

In an internal document at work I saw reference to an HTTP POST method for deploying content from one sharepoint site to another.  Is this how deployment services actually works?  There isn't much documentation from Microsoft about this.

EDIT: Let me be more specific.  Here's the quote from the document:

> The Content Staging Farm will publish (export) content to the production environment via an HTTP post to the Central Administration web application that administers the production public facing web application. The production application server will then import this content into the appropriate SQL Server content databases and make it available to the public.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple:

1. Export data from sharepoint to files on filesystem (the files can be compressed).
2. Push files to server on the remote farm via HTTP.
3. Import data from files on filesystem to content database (runs on server that the files were pushed to).

Remove the files.